# Cloudscraper with proxies works locally on windows, but not on a linux server?

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-requests, cloudflare

When I make a request with cloudscraper using proxies locally on my windows PC, it works. However, on linux using the same proxies, it fails.

I'm attempting to scrape data from a betting odds comparison website oddschecker.com, and I am initially making a request to the homepage to determine if I have a useable client for the remainder of the scrape.

For the sake of simplicity, here is a small amount of code to replicate what I want to do:

```
import cloudscraper

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper(ecdhCurve="brainpoolP224r1", interpreter="nodejs")
# proxy = do_what_it_is_to_get_proxy
# scraper.proxies.update(proxy)

response = scraper.get('https://www.oddschecker.com/', headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("request success")
```

I'm cycling through a few ecdhCurves, but the one in the code is one that works at the time of asking this question. It may need running a few times to get a 200 response.

Now when I run this locally on my windows PC using proxies I have access to, it works. But when I run the same code on a linux server using the same proxies, it continuously fails with 403 responses. Has anyone had this happen before? I know cloudscraper extends from python requests, does linux handle requests differently than windows or maybe the target site recognises the request is being made by a linux server? Would like a solution, but also keen to know why this might be happening.

I am using Python 3.9 on both machines. May also be worth mentioning that I don't have this problem using cloudscraper for other websites.